# accessing variables created in the override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() function outside that function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelB: UILabel!


    var dataPassed:String!
    var secondDataPassed:String!
    var newVar: String!
    var newVar2: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelA.text = dataPassed
        labelB.text = secondDataPassed
        newVar = labelA.text
         println(newVar)
    }


 println(newVar) *** I can't access newVar outside override func viewDidLoad() { - Gives "expected declaration" Its driving me crazy!!!***

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: to avoid confusion - the println within the function works fine

Answer (score 0):

Is there any data in dataPassed? If you don't assign any String to your dataPassed variable, and then you assign newVar to dataPassed, newVar will have nothing to print.

Try:

```
    import UIKit

   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelB: UILabel!


    var dataPassed:String! = "Test."
    var secondDataPassed:String!
    var newVar: String!
    var newVar2: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelA.text = dataPassed
        labelB.text = secondDataPassed
        newVar = labelA.text
         println(newVar)
    }
```

Secondly, it appears that you're trying to `println` again outside of the function. That isn't going to work, because viewDidLoad is essentially the "main method" of your app. You can create other functions that respond to button touches, etc... and run a println there, but because Swift code is executed functionally, the code you're executing has to be inside of a particular function. While you can declare variables, as you have, you can't perform actions such as printing them outside of a function, because then there's no order/method to the madness.

The only place where you can run Swift code on a standalone basis without functions is in a Swift Playground. In XCode you can select File -> New -> Playground to try this out.

Comment: Thanks - yes there is data in dataPassed it comes from a segue in my ViewController.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to access the data  within the function so I can add it to an array which will finally be written to a file. My actual app has a lot more views and data I have used this example to try and understand how I can achieve this.
What I wish to achieve is to carry data from scene to scene and add data from each scene to the final array.
I suppose one could write data to a temp. file and read it in, add data and write back to file, but surely there is an easier way

Comment: If you want to use persistent data, you could try storing such a value in NSUserDefaults. Not that this is the best way, it is perhaps a simple workaround.

Comment: Thank you - you put me on the right track - a button and @IBAction func press(sender: AnyObject) etc fixed the problem. You have cleared-up a Swift "mystery" I could not get my head around! Thanks